# Отключение IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, внедрение

Допустим, есть интерфейс `IConnection`. Он в своей иерархии имеет `IDisposable`.

Далее, есть класс, который реализует(Допустим, `SqlConnection`) `IConnection`.

Я создаю экземпляр этого класса и передаю его, как зависимости в 2 других класса, так как хочу, что бы они пользовались 1 соединением.

Проблема в том, что эти 2 объекта ничего не знают о том, что делят 1 соединение => они внутри себя могут реализовать `IDisposable`, где вызвать `Dispose` соединения => другой объект в один прекрасный момент крашнится из-за того, что соединение было закрыто.

На ум приходит создание `Proxy`, который будет вызывать пустой `Dispose`().

Есть еще какие-то варианты? Скажем, что бы не плодить прокси-классы.

Comment: Прокси классы тут - самый правильный вариант. Вы существующую абстракцию соединения хотите изменить, значит и класс должен быть другим, скрывающим где то внутри себя особенность того, что соединение переиспользуется.

Comment: Не передавайте один экземпляр — передавайте разные

Comment: Значит два других класса не являются владельцами соединения и не должны его закрывать.

Comment: @Igor ну это если классы свои. А если не свои - то прокси поможет избежать ненужного закрытия.

Comment: Для многопоточного кода, реализация с прокси может быть не тривиальной.

Comment: Лучше всего передавать 2 разных экземпляра.
Но если сильно нужно, то как вариант можно трекать стейт, и закрывать соединение только если никто им не пользуется т.е. когда уходит последний. А в Dispose делать по сути отписку.

Comment: Нелегальный способ - теоретически можно перебить Dispose в таблице виртуальных функций. Я с похожей проблемой сталкивался - пришлось прокси-класс писать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё это не очень по нескольким причинам

1. Дизайн. Наследование от `IDisposable` другим интерфейсом постулирует нам о необходимости реализации интерфейса как нечто, что имеет высвобождаемые ресурсы. Плохая идея думать, что все реализации интерфейса «соединение» должны высвобождать ресурсы (есть тесты, как минимум). Следовательно, реализация `IDisposable` это необходимость для конкретного класса (например, `SqlConnection` и т.д.), а не интерфейса.
2. Существует [композиция и аггрегация](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2012/12/vs-vs.html). При аггрегации время жизни вашего объекта  определяет внешний контекст, а не класс где вы его используете (это свойство композиции). Вы описываете аггрегацию.
3. Большинство контейнеров зависимостей реализуют правила 3R: Register, Resolve, *Release*. Это, в том числе, значит, что контейнер может вызвать `Dispose` после окончания времени жизни объекта (`Scope`)

---

Собственно, решение можно подсмотреть у любого контекста подобного рода, например EF, где контекст регистрируется один на запрос (*PerRequest*) в случае веба. Либо использует пул/фабрику. Конкретная реализация будет зависить от конкретного кода.

Answer (score 3):

> они внутри себя могут реализовать IDisposable, где вызвать Dispose

Если они это классы в которые заинжектили экземпляры IConnection, то высвобождать такой ресурс плохая практика, т.к. они их не порождали и понятия не имеют где они еще используются. В диспосе нужно высвобождать только ресурсы которые были созданы самим этим классом. Да и сейчас почти во всех DI-контейнерах  можно задавать время жизни объектов.